# It is correct to put 'But' before 'Despite of'?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis, conjunctions

I want to write: But despite of this.......

Is putting two conjunctions together not necessary? Or would it be fine to have them both together right up close next to each other.

Comment: "Despite of" is ungrammatical in any case.

Comment: What would you recommend as an replacement?

Comment: It would be grammatical if you removed "of".

Answer (score 1):

I would just write, "Despite this...." Addition of "But" is unnecessary. You already have your transition with the word "despite," and readers know that "this" refers to the previously discussed topic. "I have done this for many years. Despite this, I still make mistakes on occasion."

Answer (score 1):

Leave out the *of*.

You also might try:

> But in spite of this, ...

It means the same, and you might find it flows better.

Answer (score -3):

You can only use one conjunction, but in some sentences, you can use both in rare cases, here the sentence is correct.

Comment: I'm downvoting this not because it's an opportunity to give an example of consecutive conjunctions, but because - and *only* because - the assertion is incorrect.